# Please Explain what the ? {$_} is doing here after the pipe

Tags: powershell

below is some PowerShell output.  Can someone please explain to me the difference between including the | ? {$_} and not including it (apart from the obvious visual output differences)?  This is not as part of a bigger script or anything, I am starting out in PowerShell and am trying to understand some of the basic intricacies.  I understand splitting using regex part.

```
PS C:\Users\oucs0058> $pc = "123456789ABCDE"
PS C:\Users\oucs0058> $pc -split '(..)'

12

34

56

78

9A

BC

DE

PS C:\Users\oucs0058> $pc -split '(..)' | ? {$_}
12
34
56
78
9A
BC
DE
```

Comment: `? {$_}` read it as: `where actual valued piped is not null`

Comment: Surely there aren't any nulls?  (Or rather surely there are going by the first output). Why are there Nulls?

Comment: Actually, it's not nulls, but empty strings. However, `$null` is `$false` when casted to boolean, so this does not make any difference (see my answer on the casting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the `?` shorthand, you're actually using the `Where-Object` cmdlet. This cmdlet evaluates the argument script block, which should return with a boolean value. The input object is passed down the pipeline if the evaluation comes back with `$true` and ignored if the evaluation comes back with `$false`. For instance, `Where-Object $true` will pass all input objects and `Where-Object $false` will pass none of them.

The script block can be anything, but its results are casted to a boolean. Due to this, when you write `{$_}`, you are casting the input string object into a boolean. PowerShell casts empty strings to `$false` and non-empty ones to `$true`.

Your `$pc -split '(..)'` command returns a list of string objects, every second of them empty. Due to this, the `{$_}` will return `$false` for empty strings and `$true` for non-empty strings and the rest if pretty straightforward: `Where-Object` will pass on non-empty strings and ignore the empty ones. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Then why is every second string empty when doing the split in the first place?

Comment: Good question, I _think_ that has to do with .NET String.split() behavior, which says _"If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array."_ (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx). This condition is satisfied by the input + the regex.

Comment: Great info and +1 for the msdn link!